# Save a GeoTIFF one band with palette

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I am using QGIS 3.12.3 on Windows.

I am loading a tif file (CRS EPSG:3395 - WGS 84 / World Mercator - Projected, 1 Band with a palette with 256 colors), and I am trying to just save it "as it is" to another tif file (that is not the final goal obviously).

When I do that, just selecting a file name and leaving all other options unchanged, I end up with a layer with 1 band and a palette of just 2 colors black and white. I can copy/paste the style in the newly created layer to get my colors back, but I am stuck on how to actually save it into a tif file.

I have tried many things, I know I can save it as an image but I don't want that, I want to keep it as a one band/palette GeoTIFF, using the same CRS etc.

The final goal is just to crop the tif, keeping the same palette/resolution/projection/etc.

Comment: I don't have QGIS in front of me right now, but I'm wondering if you are saving the output as a 1-bit raster, which only gives you two colors, black and white.  What happens when you set the output bit depth to 8, which gives 256 colors?

Comment: Could be, but I don't see any options in the "save as" dialog for specifying bit depth